# I need to combine two select queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to combine the second query as a column in the first queries results.

First query:

```
Select
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.Player,
  Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Points + snpc_stats.gamedetail.Hits) As Points,
  COUNT(*) As 'Games Played',
  Avg(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Finish) As 'Average Finish',
  Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Hits) As `Total Hits`

From
  snpc_stats.gamedetail Inner Join
  snpc_stats.games On MOM_snpc_stats.games.GameID =
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.GamesID

Where
  snpc_stats.games.Season = '2014 Season'

Group By
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.Player, MOM_snpc_stats.games.Season

Order By
  Points Desc
```

Second query:

```
Select
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.Player,
  Sum(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Finish) As Second

From
  snpc_stats.gamedetail Inner Join
  snpc_stats.games On MOM_snpc_stats.games.GameID = snpc_stats.gamedetail.GamesID

Where
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.Finish = 1 And
  snpc_stats.games.Season = '2014 Season'

Group By
  snpc_stats.gamedetail.Player, snpc_stats.games.Season
```

Not sure how to go about this...

Comment: As a column? You can `SELECT (select ...) AS \`something\`` - but if that sub query has more than 1 result you may be f'd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following column to your `select` statement in the first query:

```
sum(if(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Finish = 1, 1, 0)) as Second
```

Since you're joining and grouping by the same things in both queries, you should just be able to add this as a column without any further joins or subqueries.